# select dropdown element with testing-library

Tags: testing-library

I do not understand testing-library at all apparently.  They have a "click" function, but there doesn't appear to be a function for selecting a simple drop down option from a select element.  This is failing, saying that 0 is selected, and not the expected 1.  How do I make the selection work?

```js
import React from "react";
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'
import {screen} from '@testing-library/dom'

let container: any;
beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

it('AddRental should display', () => {
    render(<select name="town" data-testid="town" className="form-control"
                   aria-label="Select the Town">
        <option value="0">--Town--</option>
        <option value="1">My town</option>
        <option value="2">Your Town</option>
        <option value="3">The other town</option>
    </select>, {container});
    const dropdown = screen.getByTestId('town');
    expect(dropdown.value)
        .toBe('0');
    dropdown.click();
    const athabascaOption = screen.getByText('My town');
    athabascaOption.click();
    const byTestId = screen.getByTestId('town');
    expect(byTestId.value)
        .toBe('1')
});
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`fireEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireeventeventname) for this purpose. It can be imported from `@testing-library/react` (so can `screen`, by the way, for convenience):

```js
import {render, screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
```

Here is your test case rewritten to use this function:

```js
render(
    <select
        name="town"
        data-testid="town"
        className="form-control"
        aria-label="Select the Town"
    >
        <option value="0">--Town--</option>
        <option value="1">My town</option>
        <option value="2">Your Town</option>
        <option value="3">The other town</option>
    </select>,
    { container },
);
const dropdown = screen.getByTestId('town') as HTMLSelectElement;
expect(dropdown.value).to.equal('0');
fireEvent.change(dropdown, { target: { value: '1' } });
expect(dropdown.value).to.equal('1');
```

For further explanation, there is some useful discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/256) and [this CodeSandbox from a comment on the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacttestinglibrary-demo-prj6h?file=/src/__tests__/App.js).

Comment: How about `userEvent.selectOptions(dropdown, '1');`